# Back button on fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost, back

How can i translate fragment when i click back button?

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, new RMBTStartFragment());
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by translate.

Comment: change current fragment by other fragment

Comment: what is wrong in the correct code. you replace the existing framgent with a new one by adding it to the container.

Comment: but this code must be executed when i click the back button of devise

Comment: The code is correct, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

put your code into

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
              // your code
            }
    else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and put `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` in your `onCreate`